# Replace all null with spaces before writing data out in the spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is how i replace all `null` with `""` .

```
val dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull = dfMainOutputFinal.withColumn("concatenated", regexp_replace(col("concatenated"), "null", "")).withColumnRenamed("concatenated", header)

dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull.repartition(1).write.partitionBy("DataPartition","StatementTypeCode")
  .format("csv")
  .option("nullValue", "")
  .option("delimiter", "\t")
  .option("quote", "\u0000")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("codec", "gzip")
  .save("s3://trfsmallfffile/FinancialLineItem/output")
```

But my problem is this replaces the null in the record also .
For example

Wherever `annullment` is found in the record after my scipt i get `ament` .

How can i replace null only if it is found as null column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below

```
val dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull = dfMainOutputFinal.withColumn("concatenated", regexp_replace(col("concatenated"), "|^|null", "")).withColumnRenamed("concatenated", header)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
`dfMainOutputFinal.na.fill("")`

See https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameNaFunctions.html